# Hiding/Making an object visible affect the material colors of an unrelated Object

Tags: materials, objects, color

I'm fairly new to Blender, but I'm having fun working on resculpting a Ratchet model from the Transformers Prime Wii game, and everything's been going pretty smoothly so far. I, however, encountered an odd, small, but otherwise aggravating situation.

I have all Ratchet's pieces sorted into collections, and have been assigning materials to them as I resculpt and the like, and it seems, for some reason, that toggling some items in the Faceplates category between visible and hidden changes the colors on a very specific set of faces on his Windshields(made by constructing one and mirroring the other, btw), located in the Chassis category.

Having these objects visible makes this corner of the Windshields white, and hiding them reverts them to red, what they're supposed to be. The weird thing is, some of these pieces don't have the red or white materials applied to them in the first place.

I will have to add the actual Blend file later, as I'm typing this on mobile. My laptop has poor internet connection.

The only other duplicate/mirrored pieces that affect this is the "Right Optic Ridge," (basically his eyebrow) made by duplicating the Left optic ridge. Everything else is standard as far as the imported OBJ goes, I think.

[image: The circled Colors show as white here]

[image: When hiding certain Facial features, they're red as they're meant to be]

[image: The facial features that are currently hidden are what affects the Windshields]

[image: List of Chassis pieces if that helps]

[image: List of Materials currently in the file itself]

Comment: Next time use a screen capture app for better readability.

Comment: Please use Blender's built-in Screenshot generator to produce images. You can use Window > Save Screenshot to save the whole window or Window > Save Screenshot (Editor) then click on an area if you just want to save an image of one of Blender's areas.

Comment: For your own debugging purposes, and to make your problem easier to understand for a complete stranger to your project, I would also suggest isolating just a couple of components that illustrate the unwanted behaviour.. strip it down as much as possible.